# Force user To check a Checkbox in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have designed a registration form for my Website and now I put a check box for Terms and Conditions acceptance which is defined in Model.

Now I want to now is there any way to force user to check that checkbox or not?

If it is pre-defined in ASP.NET MVC, I use it to check both server side and client side and if not I use Javascript for that.

Here is my code

*RegisterViewModel*

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} نمی تواند خالی باشد")]
    [RegularExpression("^[\u0600-\u06FF\u0698\u067E\u0686\u06AF ]{2,}$", ErrorMessage = "نام فقط شامل الفبای فارسی می باشد.")]
    [StringLength(32, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "طول نام کاربری بین 4 تا 32 کاراکتر است.")]
    [Display(Name = "نام")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} نمی تواند خالی باشد")]
    [RegularExpression("^[\u0600-\u06FF\u0698\u067E\u0686\u06AF ]{2,}$", ErrorMessage = "نام فقط شامل الفبای فارسی می باشد.")]
    [StringLength(32, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "طول نام کاربری بین 4 تا 32 کاراکتر است.")]
    [Display(Name = "نام خانوادگی")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} نمی تواند خالی باشد")]
    [Phone]
    [Display(Name = "شماره تلفن")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} نمی تواند خالی باشد")]
    [Display(Name = "جنسیت")]
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} نمی تواند خالی باشد")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_]+$", ErrorMessage = "نام کاربری شامل الفبای انگلیسی، اعداد و آندرلاین می باشد.")]
    [StringLength(16, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "طول نام کاربری بین 4 تا 16 کاراکتر است.")]
    [Display(Name = "نام کاربری")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} نمی تواند خالی باشد")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "پست الکترونیک به درستی وارد نشده است.")]
    [Display(Name = "پست الکترونیک")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} نمی تواند خالی باشد")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "پسوورد باید بین {0} و {2} کاراکتر باشد.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "رمز عبور")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} نمی تواند خالی باشد")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "تکرار رمز عبور")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "رمز عبور با تکرارش همخوانی ندارد.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsAgreeWithTerms { get; set; }
```

*Register View*

```
<section class="register-area">
<div class="row m-1">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 p-0">
        <div class="register-content">
            <div class="d-table">
                <div class="d-table-cell">
                    <div class="register-form">
                        <h3><i class="bx bx-user"></i> ثبت نام در ایران پی سی جِی</h3>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="row m-1">
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-m-6">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Firstname, new { @class = "form-control", @placeHolder = "نام" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Firstname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-m-6">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeHolder = "نام خانوادگی" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-m-6">
                            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, "--جنسیت--", new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-m-6">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @placeHolder = "شماره تلفن" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-m-6">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "form-control", @placeHolder = "نام کاربری" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-m-6">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @placeHolder = "ایمیل" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-m-6">
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @placeHolder = "رمز عبور" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-m-6">
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", @placeHolder = "تکرار رمز عبور" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-m-6 terms">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsAgreeWithTerms)
                            با <a href="#">قوانین و شرایط</a> ایران پی سی جِی موفق هستم.
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-m-6">
                            <button type="submit">ثبت نام</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

So is there any way to forbid user from submitting form without checking `IsAgreeWithTerms` field?

Thanks for responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your custom validation attribute that inherits from `IClientValidatable` to enforce the value being true when doing validation on the server-side and client-side, but if you don't want to do the extra setup, the simplest approach is to re-use the existing validation attributes.

#### Server-side Validation Only

You can use `[Range]` to enforce a true value on a checkbox.

```cs
[Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "You need to agree first!")]
public bool IsAgreeWithTerms { get; set; }
```

#### Both Client and Server-side validation

If you want the client-side validation to work as well, instead of using `[Range]`, we need to use `[Compare]` with a read-only field declared as `true` in the view model:

```cs
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    public bool ExpectedAgreement => true;

    [Compare(nameof(ExpectedAgreement),ErrorMessage = "You need to agree first!")]
    public bool IsAgreeWithTerms { get; set; }
}
```

Then on the view, you will need to store that read-onl property into a hidden input:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(...))
{
    ...

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ExpectedAgreement)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsAgreeWithTerms)
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IsAgreeWithTerms)
        <div class="text-danger">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.IsAgreeWithTerms)
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that doesn't work. I have some funny solution. can I define a Boolean field with true value and I use Compare annotation to compare my field with that?

Comment: Please see my updates. `[Range]` only worked for server-side validation. If you want client-side validation as well, yes use `[Compare]` approach.

Comment: Thank you buddy <3